# Swift - How can I compare the values of a collection of variables?

Tags: swift

I have 7 variables called `averageMon`, `averageTue`, `averageWed`, and so on, and I need to compare the value stored in each variable to see which holds the highest value. I've been looking around but haven't found a way to do this. I'm brand new to this, and I'm sure this is a simple question, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Swift is no interpreted. Either you put them in a array or you use NSObject's KVC (which will anyway force you to know the names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just call the max function:

```
max(averageMon, averageTue, averageWed, averageThu, averageFri, averageSat, averageSun)
```

http://swift-ios.co/standard-functions-in-swift/